# How can I stop Github prompting me to merge changes when I change a branch?

Tags: github

I have multiple branches in my GitHub repository.  I maintain them independently and don't intend to merge them. Whenever I make changes in a branch GitHub always presents the prompt to "Compare & pull request"

For example:
[image: screenshot]

How can I make this go away?

Comment: [Webapps.SE] isn't really focused on developers, no. That said, about *every* SE site is visited mostly by developers, so you might be lucky ...

Comment: Not a complete solution. This prompt only stays for a while. I don't know how long, but as it says "...had recent pushes...", its mentioning only the recent ones. If you didn't commit to the non-primary branches for a while, then this prompt will disappear